# Channel Normalization Operator in R

Tags: r, rstudio, formula

I am new in R and I am trying to recreate a Channel Normalization Operator in R but with poor results.
The formula I am trying to compute is:

```
CNO = [(St - Smin(n))]/(Smax(n)-Smin(n)]
```

where:
St is the value of time series at time t.
Smin(n) is the minimum value of time series, last n days.
Smax(n) is the maximum value of time series, last n days.
n= channel look-back span in days (e.g. 30).

What I've done so far is:

```
t <- c(RUT_2012_2017T$Close)
n <- 30 #look back period defined by the rule
CN <- {(t - min(tail(t,n)))/((max(tail(t,n)))/(min(tail(t,n))))}
```

But it is not working because it computes only one minimum. The one at the position n-30.

Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: See the `rollmax` function from the `zoo` package.

Comment: You might reconsider your choice of terminology (or criticize the person who gave that name to this in your business math course perhaps). "Normalization" often means rescaling a variable so it has mean of zero and std deviation of 1. You are rescaling to a rolling value with a range of `[0,1]`.

Comment: (t - (-rollmax(-t,n)))/((rollmax(t,n))-((-rollmax(-t,n)))) Nicola do you mean like this? The results I get are still incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a CNO function which calculates the CNO of the last compnent of its argument and pass it to `rollapplyr`.  For purposes of example we have used a random series 25 long and a moving window width of 5.

```
library(zoo)

set.seed(123)
x <- rgamma(25, 1) # test data

CNO <- function(x) (tail(x, 1) - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
rollapplyr(x, 5, CNO, fill = NA)
```

It could alternately be done like this (also using zoo):

```
mx <- rollmaxr(x, 5, fill = NA)
mn <- - rollmaxr(-x, 5, fill = NA)
(x - mn) / (mx - mn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
doFx <- function(pos, len, x, fx) fx(x[(pos-len):pos])

len <- 100
t <- rnorm(len) # just some numbers to work with
n <- 30

# calculations for t[30:100]

Smin <- sapply(n:len, doFx, n, t, min)
Smax <- sapply(n:len, doFx, n, t, max)

CN <- (t[n:len] - Smin)/(Smax - Smin)
```

Your equations differed, so this was my best guess.